# How to generate same seqnumber for a same itemIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
with t as (

           select 'AA-00001152' itemid from dual union all

           select 'AA-00001152' from dual union all

           select 'AA-00001153' from dual union all

           select 'AA-00001154' from dual union all

           select 'AA-00001154' from dual union all

           select 'CC-254565' from dual union all

           select 'AA-00001156' from dual union all

           select 'AA-00001156' from dual union all

           select 'BB-00001200' from dual

          )

select  14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) seq_no,

        itemid

  from  t

  order by seq_no
```

Here i have generated seq_no for multiple itemIds, but i am trying to update in a seq_no column which is throwing error saying subquery returns more than one row. Please help in update query. thanks.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MS SQL Server?

Comment: can you also post your update query please

Comment: update t set seq_no=(select 14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) seq_no from t) 
giving error as subquery returns more than one row.

    SEQ_NO ITEMID

---------- -----------

     15000 AA-00001152

     15000 AA-00001152

     15001 AA-00001153

     15002 AA-00001154

     15002 AA-00001154

     15003 AA-00001156

     15003 AA-00001156

     15004 BB-00001200

     15005 CC-254565

Comment: Try row_number() instead of dense_rank()

Comment: do u have duplicate row data ?

Comment: you do not need to use subquery for update use this and instead and check   `update t set seq_no= 14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid)  from t`

Comment: I guess you also need to declare seq_no column in cte or join Cte with Dual table

Comment: pls send the query..as am learner in mssql

Comment: Post your table DDL and the update you are trying to do so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need insert query, not update. This should work

```
declare @Dual table  ( Itemid varchar(20), seq_no int)
;

with t (itemid) as (

               select 'AA-00001152'   union all

               select 'AA-00001152'  union all

               select 'AA-00001153'  union all

               select 'AA-00001154'  union all

               select 'AA-00001154'  union all

               select 'CC-254565'  union all

               select 'AA-00001156'  union all

               select 'AA-00001156'  union all

               select 'BB-00001200' 

              )
insert into @Dual (Itemid,seq_no)
select itemid, 14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) from t

select * from @Dual
```

Comment: `Dual` is a special table in Oracle, seems he is trying to migrate a script to SQL Server.

Comment: ah is it `dual` from Oracle dummy table, he is not clear in his question then , that would be a joke if he is trying to migrate from Oracle with update query

Comment: still am unable to update the seq_no column...
Update d
     set seq_no =(  14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) from test d 
    inner join   test t1 on    d.itemid = t.itemid)

Comment: @badri please tell us clearly, are you trying to migrate script from oracle to sql ?. do u have seq_no column in a table or is it a derived column

Comment: first i tried using oracle sql query to insert data into tables...then i tried using insert data into tables in mssql.

Comment: @badri updated script to suit your needs, please check

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you could use `cte` as temporary result set in order to update sequence in table

```
;with t as (
      select *, 
              14999 + dense_rank() over(order by itemid) Seq
      from table t
)

update t1 set seq_no = t.Seq 
from table t1 inner join t on t.itemid = t1.itemid
```